# Starting an app using supervisor in Elixir which would automatically restart on error

Tags: task, elixir, erlang-supervisor

I am able to run an app on elixir but if an error occurs, everything exists. I just want that my app restarts in this case. I am using supervisor but don't even know if it's working. Following is my code:-

mix.exs:-

```
def application do
[ 
  applications: [:httpotion, :zookeeper, :parallel, :poison],
  mod: {ServiceMonitor, []}
]
end
```

service_monitor.ex

```
defmodule ServiceMonitor do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
        worker(ServiceMonitor.Registry.setup, []),
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

registry.ex

```
defmodule ServiceMonitor.Registry do

  def setup do
    zk = get_zk
    start(zk)
  end

  def start(zk) do
    #main code
  end
end
```

Now i am running my app using the command:-

```
MIX_ENV=test mix run
```

It all runs well until i receive an error in my main code. Application exists and never restarts. Error i receive is:-

```
** (Mix) Could not start application service_monitor: exited in: ServiceMonitor.start(:normal, [])
** (EXIT) exited in: Task.await(%Task{owner: #PID<0.164.0>, pid: #PID<0.169.0>, ref: #Reference<0.0.2.1026>}, 3600000)
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :no_node}
            (service_monitor) lib/service_monitor/registry.ex:121: anonymous fn/3 in ServiceMonitor.Registry.remove_available_if_not_registered/3
            (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:89: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
            (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:40: Task.Supervised.reply/5
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Kindly help as to where i am going wrong. My requirement is that app should automatically restart as soon as error is received.

Comment: Does this work: `worker(ServiceMonitor.Registry, [], function: :setup)`? If not, can you please post the contents of `ServiceMonitor.Registry.start/1`?

Comment: no this is also giving the same error. start function is like this:-
`def start(zk) do
  #some code
start(zk)
end`

Basically it is an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

If `ServiceMonitor` is your Supervisor module, it should use `Supervisor` instead of importing `Supervisor.spec` according to [this](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html).

**Edit**:
If you want still to go with your supervisor, try to add `Supervisor.start` at the end of your code, just like in example:

```
defmodule KVServer do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
    # worker(KVServer.Worker, [arg1, arg2, arg3])
    ]

   opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: KVServer.Supervisor]
   Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
 end
end
```

Comment: If I do that, it says `** (CompileError) lib/service_monitor.ex:11: undefined function worker/3`

Comment: Remove this `use Application` and instead paste `use Supervisor`. You shouldn't import Supervisor.spec in the function as well. Also name of the function, where `worker/3` will be called should be `init`.

Comment: now when i run my app using `MIX_ENV=test mix run` , i get the error:-
`** (Mix) Could not start application service_monitor: exited in: ServiceMonitor.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function ServiceMonitor.start/2`

Comment: i have done exactly what you told in your edited answer 
`defmodule ServiceMonitor do
    use Application

   def start(_type, _args) do
     import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

     children = [
        worker(ServiceMonitor.Registry, [], function: :setup),
     ]

     opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: ServiceMonitor.Supervisor]
     Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
   end
end` 
But i am still getting the same error

Comment: this function just returns the zookeeper client, that's why i haven't written it above. It is basically :- `def get_zk do
        case ZK.start(@zk_quorams) do
            {:ok, zk} -> zk
        end
    end`

Comment: Logically code is working fine. I just want supervisor to restart automatically when i get some error in my code. It should be possible right?

Comment: I'm not so sure. Just try out.